# Grid view like Windows 8 or Google Play

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, windows-8, google-play

I'm looking for the source code, or an example, of a gridview.
I know that with eclipse i can do something really simple: many squares next to each other.

But i want to have something strange and particular like this example:

Click [here](https://lh3.ggpht.com/8iGKqq0ASPrFcHoypSnJIID5qQbdiOAEAnDvo8uWgCPBbR68rLK3PNuvtZiiyXSqYp0i=h310-rw)

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StaggerdGridview from Here [Github](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo)

It Looks Like This

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it seems StaggeredGridView is designed for all of the columns to have equal width - which is not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through layout nesting. It's basically just like doing your html pages. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="226dp"
            android:background="@color/dark_shadow">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/holo_bright_blue">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >

            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="154dp"
                    android:background="@color/me_blue">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="106dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@color/dark_shadow">
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray">
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also make use of the layout weight and weight sum of the parent container is you need to add other views inside those layouts. Hope this will give you some hints on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Good answer! The problem is that: if i change the dimensions of the screen (using a tablet, or a phone with another size-screen), this layout DOESN'T remain constant!!
Please help me :)

Comment: You need to create another layout for those devices. Create a new folder in your res folder and name it layout-sw600dp. this will give you support for screens with 600dp width such as 7" tablets. You will then redo your layout in tablet format but make sure it has the same name with your default layout. Android has it's ways to detect on which layout to load for a certain devices. For more information read it here

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html