# Windows Tile Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am looking for windows 8 tile layout in android (Layout exactly like windows phone tile UI.. ). tried alot with table/grid layout. couldn't make it perfect. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: an android device does not run windows so you shouldnt make your app look like a windows device. would you make a windows app look like an iOS app?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19113993/2777098

Comment: try to use asymmetric gridview

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.26"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="118dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" 
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="122dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.84"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="118dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="122dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way it works may be

```
<com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AsymmetricGridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (AsymmetricGridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Choose your own preferred column width
    listView.setRequestedColumnWidth(Utils.dpToPx(this, 120));
    final List<AsymmetricItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // initialize your items array
    adapter = new ListAdapter(this, listView, items);
    AsymmetricGridViewAdapter asymmetricAdapter =
        new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<>(this, listView, adapter);
    listView.setAdapter(asymmetricAdapter);
}
```

for more see [here](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@color/backPink"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@color/dark_green" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/dark_blue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/Teal" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/purple" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Click Here to view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGikf.jpg)